# An error in creating file in c#.net

Tags: c#

I tried to create a file with `File.Create` but I get an error. I can't fix that. I searched for this problem and found this code and I copied it to Visual Studio but it still has this error :

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Access to the path 'C:\aaa.txt' is denied.

My code:

```
string path = "C:\\aaa.txt";

if (File.Exists(path))
{
    Console.WriteLine("file exist");
}
else
{
    using (FileStream fs = File.Create(path))
    {
        Byte[] info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("This is some text in the file.");

        fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try not writing to the root !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stop trying to create files at the root of drive C:; standard users are forbidden from that, and it's a bad idea even for administrators. If this is a user's file put it in the user's folder:

```
string path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "aaa.txt");
```

If it's not a user file look through the [`Environment.SpecialFolder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.110).aspx) values to find the folder to put it in.

Comment: I tried to create in other folder . It worked . thank

Answer (score -1):

I hope you understand the error but in simple words it means that you don't have the permission to modify/write to the path.

So,why not just run your app as administrator ?..

Create an application manifest file(Right click project > Add > New Item > Application Manifest file) and add this :

```
   <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

One last thing, if you really want to create a simple text file,why not just use one line code such as `File.WriteAllTexr` ??

Comment: I add it in manifest but doesn't worked . I am learning c#.net so i am beginner at it and i don't know a lot of code in dot net

Comment: I wish i could invite you on skype but i don't know if it is the right thing to do .... Also i cannot explain it all here as it may become huge..However, you cannot even reply to SO chat because you have vere few reputation